# An investigator planned repeated measures on n individuals with K time points but the sample size changes due to death-event after each time points?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, survival, sample-size, clinical-trials

Suppose an investigator planned repeated measures on n individuals with K time points but the sample size changes due to death-event after each time point. The investigator seeks to predict the cause of death by using continuous variables measured at each time point at each individual. how to calculate sample size and what will be the appropriate statistical analysis method for this kind of research problem?

Comment: What is the single hypothesis proposed?

Comment: Regression analysis